# How can I remove "u" in python 2.7.13, while fetching data from sqlite3 and displaying it with a tkmessagebox

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

This is the code I am executing to extract data but the unicode's "u" 
is not getting removed

```
cur=con.cursor()
e1=self.entry1.get()
e2=self.entry2.get()
e3=self.entry3.get()
e4=self.entry4.get()
cur.execute("insert into student13 values(?,?,?,?)",(e1,e2,e3,e4))
con.commit()
cur.execute("select * from student13")
ar=cur.fetchall()
>#fetching data from database
tkMessageBox.showinfo("records",ar)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the ".encode" function

```
ar = u'unicode string'
ar = ar.encode('ascii')
```